# Adding more JqueryUI combobox to one page with button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I have a page where i have one JqueryUI autocomplete combobox (like this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) and i want add more comboboxes with a button (when i click the button, i add the new combobox with jquery .append function).
But when i click on the button a simple html select dropdown appears, not the combobox.
I want all the added bomboboxes to be autocomplete comboboxes, like the first one.

You can see the example here:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/Q48jV/]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q48jV/

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code add

```
$('.dropdownclass').combobox()
```

after append the div

http://jsfiddle.net/Q48jV/1/